# type '_Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>

Tags: android, flutter, dart

```
final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(AppUrl.getBooking), 
  headers: headers,
  body: data);
var map = jsonDecode(response.body);
   for(var r in map){
          log(r['name'].toString());
   }
```

first time value come but when i again come to this page its show error
Unhandled Exception: type '_Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable'

please help me to solve this.

i want to show table_calender event via api using provider.

Comment: share more code to enable me to know how to help you.

Comment: jsonDecode(response.body) is Map, you cannot iterate it. Share response.body.

Comment: Probably the decoded json is will have another object e.g var tmp = jsonDecode(response.body); map = tmp['listvalues'];  ( assuming listvalues is an object containing list in the json )

Sharing more code and json data would help to know the issue more